# Rest API (Gradle) :bootJar doesn't include data.json file/can't seem to find it in the jar

Tags: java, spring, api, rest, gradle

title basically says it all.

I have written a Rest API and whenever I export to a .jar using :bootJar it gives me the following error:

```
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.2)

2022-08-22 14:43:27.390  INFO 14202 --- [           main] xxx            : Starting xxx using Java 18 on xxx with PID 14202 (/Users/OP/Desktop/api.jar started by OP in /Users/OP/Desktop)
2022-08-22 14:43:27.394  INFO 14202 --- [           main] xxx            : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-08-22 14:43:27.822  INFO 14202 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-08-22 14:43:27.829  INFO 14202 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-08-22 14:43:27.829  INFO 14202 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
2022-08-22 14:43:27.869  INFO 14202 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-08-22 14:43:27.869  INFO 14202 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 448 ms
2022-08-22 14:43:27.895  WARN 14202 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'controller': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./src/data/data.json (No such file or directory)
2022-08-22 14:43:27.897  INFO 14202 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-08-22 14:43:27.902  INFO 14202 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-08-22 14:43:27.912 ERROR 14202 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'controller': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./src/data/data.json (No such file or directory)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:160) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at de.xxx.main(xxx:10) ~[classes!/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[api.jar:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./src/data/data.json (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:111) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:60) ~[na:na]
    at de.xxx.controller.Controller.populateComponents(Controller.java:124) ~[classes!/:na]
    at de.xxx.controller.Controller.init(Controller.java:42) ~[classes!/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong but with every API I built 'till now, I never had a similar problem.

If you've got any questions I'll do my best to answer everything.

Thanks in advance!

(The data.json is under .../src/data/data.json)
And a screenshot of my file structure:

[image: file structure]

*EDIT FOR M.DEINUM*

The two Methods I was referring to:

```
public void populateComponents() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Component[] everyComponent = objectMapper.readValue(new FileReader("./src/main/resources/data.json"), Component[].class);

        for (Component c : everyComponent) {
            compMap.put(c.getNumber(), c);
        }
    }


    public void writeComponents() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        File file = new File("./src/main/resources/data.json");

        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        mapper.writeValue(file, compMap.values());

        populateComponents();
    }
```

Comment: `src/data` isn't part of theb uild so no it won't be in the resulting artifact. put it in `src/main/resources` and load it as a classpath resource.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I put it in src/main/resources and changed the references in my code. How do I "load it as a class path resource"? I'm not familiar and google spits out random articles that don't help.

Comment: `new ClassPathResource` which is  Spring class.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your instructions. Do I need to use the class path resource as my File Path for my Jackson parser? I'm sorry - real noob here

Comment: If you don't know what you are doing you might want to first understand that. You cannot access a file from within an artifact as a `java.io.File` as it isn't a resource on the filesystem. So you need to use the resource to get an inputstream. But as you didn't explain what you are actually doing it is more or less impossible to know what you should do in your exact situation.

Comment: Got it. 

Explanation to what I'm doing: I'm building a rest api for the company I work for. The Goal is to have a web interface where users are able to search for specific components and get information based on their search. Everything is done except for the second part which is compiling it into a jar. I'm using a JSON File to save data on the components - to be displayed later. I have a Jackson reader and parser to write from and to a map of components. I'm posting the code in an update to my original post

Comment: Your write won't work as you cannot write to the classpath. Your read is wrong because, as stated, you cannot use a `java.io.File`. If you need to write it you will need to place the file **outside** of the classpath in a well known location (for your app) so you can load it.

Comment: gotcha. So what do I need to change to include it in the classpath? Does is even work with the read/write I want to do?

Comment: What isn't you didn't get from this sentence -> *Your write won't work as you cannot write to the classpath.*.